# How to get and set dynamic object in Flex?

Tags: apache-flex, adobe

I found that function `"getChildByName"` can only get the object defined in `mxml`. When i must add an element with id `"dynamic_id"` dynamic.

How can i get this element?

Comment: Keep a reference to it when you add it...

Answer (score 0):

An id used in MXML will be resolved to a simple reference to a component. `public var contentGroup:Group;` for example. So you only have to add new fields to your component.